# Should one use/create as many indices as possible in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I realized, that the response to a MySQL query becomes much faster, when creating an index for the column you use for "ORDER BY", e.g.

```
SELECT username FROM table ORDER BY registration_date DESC
```

Now I'm wondering which indices I should create to optimize the request time.
For example I frequently use the following queries:

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE
    registration_date > ".(time() - 10000)."

SELECT username FROM table WHERE
    registration_date > ".(time() - 10000)."
    && status='active'

SELECT username FROM table WHERE
    status='active'

SELECT username FROM table ORDER BY registration_date DESC

SELECT username FROM table WHERE
    registration_date > ".(time() - 10000)."
    && status='active'
    ORDER BY birth_date DESC
```

**Question 1:**
Should I set up separate indices for the first three request types? (i.e. one index for the column "registration_date", one index for the column "status", and another column for the combination of both?)

**Question 2:**
Are different indices independently used for "WHERE" and for "ORDER BY"? Say, I have a combined index for the columns "status" and "registration_date", and another index only for the column "birth_date". Should I setup another combined index for the three columns ("status", "registration_date" and "birth_date")?

Comment: General rule of thumb is to put an index on any field used in a `where` or `join` clause.

Comment: Or a frequent `COUNT()` on that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard-and-fast rules for indices or query optimization. Each case needs to be considered and examined.

Generally speaking, however, you can and should add indices to columns that you frequently sort by or use in WHERE statements. (**Answer to Question 2** -- *No, the same indices are **potentially** used for `ORDER BY` and `WHERE`*) Whether to do a multi-column index or a single-column one depends on the frequency of queries. Also, you should note that single-column indices *may* be combined by mySQL using the Index Merge Optimization:

> The Index Merge method is used to retrieve rows with several range
>   scans and to merge their results into one. The merge can produce
>   unions, intersections, or unions-of-intersections of its underlying
>   scans. This access method merges index scans from a single table; it
>   does not merge scans across multiple tables.

(more reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html)

Multi-column indices also require that you take care to structure your queries in such a way that your use of indexed columns matches the column order in the index:

> MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost
>   prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statements shown
>   here:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1; SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE
>   col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2; SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE
>   col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
>
> If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3), only the first two queries
>   use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed
>   columns, but (col2) and (col2, col3) are not leftmost prefixes of
>   (col1, col2, col3).

Bear in mind that indices DO have a performance consideration of their own -- it is possible to "over-index" a table. Each time a record is inserted or an indexed column is modified, the index/indices will have to be rebuilt. This does demand resources, and depending on the size and structure of your table, it may cause a decrease in responsiveness while the index building operations are active.

Use `EXPLAIN` to find out exactly what is happening in your queries. Analyze, experiment, and don't over-do it. The shotgun approach is not appropriate for database optimization.

**Documentation**

- MySQL `EXPLAIN` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html
- How MySQL uses indices - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
- Index Merge Optimization - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: +1. Good answer. I've had very limited experience with MySQL generating a plan with an "index merge" operation. Then again, I tend towards having covering indexes for frequent queries. I fiind that I usually get the best performance when the EXPLAIN output shows "Using index".

Answer (score 1):

To quote [this page](http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases):

> [Indices] will slow down your updates and inserts.

That's the tradeoff you have to calculate. To optimize your table, you should put indices *only* in the columns you are most likely to apply conditions to - the more indices you have, the slower your data-changing operations become. In that sense, I personally don't see much merit in creating combined indices - if you create all 7 possible permutations of indices for 3 columns, you are most definitely putting more drag on your updates and inserts than just using 3 indices for 3 columns (and even that can be debatable). On the other hand, if the data is being edited much, *much* less than it is being `SELECT`ed, then indices can really help you speed things up.

Something else to take into consideration (again quoting the above page):

> If your table is very small [...] it's worse to use an index than to leave it out and just let it do a table scan. Indexes really only come in handy with tables that have a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good idea to have indexes on your column you often use, both for order by and in your where clauses.

But be aware: UPDATES, INSERTS and DELETE slow down if you have indexes.

That is because after such an operation, the index must be updated too.

So, as a rule-of-thumb: If your application is read-intensive, use the indexes where you think they help.

If your application is often updating the data, be careful, because that may get slow because of the indexes.

When in doubt, you must simply get dirty hands, and study the results of EXPLAIN.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

As for the first two examples, you can satisfy them with one index:  {registration_date, status}.  Such an index can support filters on the first item (registration_date) or on both.

It does not work for status alone, however.  The question on status is how selective is the status.  That is, what proportion of records have status = "active".  If this is a high proportion (so, on average, every database page would have an active record), then an index may not help very much.

The order by's are trickier.  I don't know if mysql uses indexes for this purpose.  Often, using an index for sorting entire records is *less* efficient than just sorting the records.  Using the index causes a random access pattern to the records in the pages, which can cause major performance problems for tables larger than the page cache.

Comment: +1 @Gordeon Linoff: yes, MySQL can make use of an index to satisfy an ORDER BY, avoiding a filesort operation. This is particularly effective when the index used is a covering index, where the query can be satisfied entirely from the index without any lookups of data pages. MySQL can also perform a "reverse scan" on an index to satisfy ORDER BY DESC.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Do you know if MySQL is smart enough not to use an index when that makes matters worse?  For instance, if the query selects two columns from a humongous table that doesn't fit into the page cache.  One column is indexed and used in the order by; the other requires accessing the table.  It is probably better to scan the table and do the file sort, rather than use the index.

Comment: Nope, mysql will use the index if it exists. That's why one must carefully select when to apply an index, or when to increase the page cache, or when to apply one of the many other optimization tricks

Comment: @Gordon: it would be "better" to have a covering index. I don't know all the ins and outs of the MySQL optimizer. I really have to look at the EXPLAIN output, and futz with hints and compare performance of the different plans. There are some clever tricks we can use SQL (e.g. wrapping a column in a "do nothing" function) to keep MySQL from considering an index.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explain function on your select statements to determine where your joins are slowing down (the more rows that are referenced, the slower it will be). Then apply your indices to those columns.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table JOIN table 2 ON a = b WHERE conditions;
```